# how to put html content over flash when wmode=window?

Tags: javascript, flash, z-index, wmode

Is this even possible?

The situation is, I don't control the embedded flash, and I have no way of knowing whether it is embedded with wmode=tranparent/opaque or wmode=window. This means in the first 2 situations I can put my html content on top, just by using z-index, but in the last situation (wmode=window) I have no control.

Does anybody know a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the whole point of wmode=window is to put the plugin in an overlay window that goes on top of the main browser window - it isn't actually possible for the browser to draw on top of it.

Comment: You can do that with iframe, se answer for question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470166/how-to-solve-zindex-issue-with-flash

Answer (score 0):

Try something called iframe shim. not sure how cross-compatible it is, but it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the reason for this but I have done this, just give some solid background color to the html most outer content with absolute position and z-index and it comes over flash with wmode=window. I did that in one of my projects back in year 2010. Main issue was IE and chrome at that time.