# how to solve zindex issue with flash

Tags: html, css, flash, z-index

In a webpage I need to show a `div` layer over the flash banner which is not using `wmode=transparent` setting.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember you can shove the div into an `<iframe>` (perhaps using Javascript so you don't make a mess of your HTML).

Iframes are window objects like flash so they're able to overlay each other.

Comment: There is a JQuery plugin to automatically do that, see the answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712476/change-the-z-index-of-flash-content/712492#712492